# App Open Ad is showing app content in place of advertisement

Tags: android, admob, ads, google-ads-api, kotlin-android

My app was getting too high CTR for AppOpenAd which was around 35%-40%. So after looking for the issue I found that the AppOpen Ad is displaying the AppContent background in place of the advertisement.
Below are the screenshots to demonstrate the exact issue.

So, in normal implementation as per the Google Admob Documentation.
Below is the picture of what is exactly happening at many times. There is a comparison between the perfect display and problem happening display.

[image: Image showing comparison of AppOpenAd Issue]

**So, to work around I tried setting the background to the AdActivity with the following style and  theme in Manifest file.**

```
<style name="Theme.AppThemeNoActionBar.AdTheme" >
    <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@null</item>
</style>
```

And setting it into manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppThemeNoActionBar.AdTheme"
        tools:replace="android:theme"/>
```

But still the issue remained same. Here the comparison picture.

[image: Image showing comparison of AppOpenAd Issue after setting theme]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? It's still happening with video install ads for me

Comment: No I couldn't found I am not sure why it was happening but it happened with only one of my apps, rest others were fine. Although I hadn't worked from past year on that app, so I don't have any updated regarding it. I even tried reaching the admob support but didn't helped much. You can still try if they have came up with any solution